# When starting a process how do I set the directory for that process to read/write files?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, file-io

In a WPF project this line is very simple to start mspaint with a given filename

```
Process.Start("mspaint.exe", filename)
```

While mspaint.exe will work with 'filename' in it's directory, if I try to open other files or do a 'SaveAs', mspaint.exe is looking at the Visual Studio \bin directory where the application was compiled to.  Even if I move the .exe elsewhere, it keeps looking at the \bin location.

I tried the following:

```
  Dim process1StartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
  process1StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\theuser\Pictures"
  process1StartInfo.FileName = "mspaint.exe"
  process1StartInfo.Arguments = filename
  process1StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
  Dim process1 = Process.Start(process1StartInfo)
```

I thought setting .WorkingDirectory would change the behavior but it does not.

Is it possible to and how do I change the directory that mspaint.exe is looking at when it is launched from within an application?  Especially after the application is compiled and moved.

Comment: Issue with programs like MSPaint is they remember the last place you saved to and bring that up as the next default. That is, they don't really use the working directory.

Comment: quick question is filename here the file name or the full path to the filename. If it is the former, try the full path.

Comment: It is the full path.